difference between hiding the image with and without setTimeout


let c = document.querySelector(".imge");
c.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    c.classList.add("hide")
  }, 0)
})
.hide {
  display: none;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" class="imge" alt="" height="100px">



without setTimeout when i run this code and drag the image i dont see the dragged image. But with it image hides but i still see the dragged image. can you explain what settimeout is doing and why this is happening?

setTimeout() makes the function run asynchronously. This allows the dragging to start before the display is updated due to the class change.

@Barmar can you better explain it? since we are adding hide class inside callback of dragstart event, dragging is started before display is updated. what is the need of settimeout. please help me

It's because one way is immediate, the other waits for the next tick of the event loop. In that second case, the drag has already started and the drag image is locked in.

@Barmar sorry i didnt understand much. can you explain the whole process in depth?

I don't know the process in detail. I'm just inferring it from the behavior.

@Barmar  then please explain briefly all that you can infer.

I thought I did. When dragging, the browser gets the image of the element being dragged when the event listener returns. In the synchronous case, the class is changed, so the element is invisible. In the async case, the class hasn't changed, so the element is visible.

@Barmar why would you think " browser gets the image of the element being dragged when the event listener returns". Shouldnt it get the image when the dragstart event starts.

Because if it did that, changing the class in the listener wouldn't make it disappear before dragging.

@Ujjawal regarding "...gets the image ... when the event listener returns ...": Generally, event handlers are executed before the standard browser behavior, so that an event handler is able to call preventDefault to cancel the event.
